# Stratified two-sample t-test in R

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test

Recently, I have started a project that needs to use stratified two-sample *t*-test. I know about one sample, independent two sample and paired *t*-test in R. My guess is that the project asks for ANOVA. How can I do stratified two-sample *t*-test in R.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158674/two-sample-tests-for-stratified-randomization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two sample tests for stratified randomization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158674/two-sample-tests-for-stratified-randomization)