# Is there a non-parametric, two-way, continuous data ANOVA for replicated repeated measures?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, continuous-data

I have data of multiple factors. Let's call them: size (2 levels), geometry (2 levels) and time (242 levels but I can limit my focus to 3 levels, which are relevant).
I also have a measure (dependent variable) called "distance", which is continuous.

Description: I measured the distance of the cells to starting point in different geometries, different pore sizes over time. There are multiple measurements for each group. It *looks like* that the distribution of the distances of these groups are different from each other.

I would like to know, if distance can be predicted by size and geometry.
My data is not normally distributed, so I would like to apply a non-parametric test.
It would be great to include all time points to compare "curves" or time-course but if not possible, it is enough to do the test on 3 relevant time points.
I am using R.

I think I cannot use:
**Friedman test**, as it is for non-replicated data.
**Kruskal Wallis**, as it is one-way (last resort?).
**OLR**, as it is for ordinal data, not continuous.

Comment: Did you measure the exact same cells at the different time points, i.e., do you have repeated measures? Can you show some histograms for groups and time points? I would possibly try fitting a GLM, possibly a GLMM. The question would only be what distribution and link function to use.

Comment: I don't have paired measurements. These are the "same" cells but they are not "connected". I don't identify each cell. These are repeated measures in the sense that I have time-course data. (I read somewhere that this "can" be taken as repeated measures.). I will try to add some histograms.

Comment: A mixed model would also work.

Comment: @user2974951 How does the mixed model work?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of misunderstandings here.  The Kruskal-Wallis test is for non-replicated data; Friedman's test is for dependent data.  (You are right, though, that these are 'one-way' tests.)  In addition, continuous data are ordinal.

Ordinal regression models (OLR / the proportional odds model) generalize tests like KW (see my answer here: [What is the non-parametric equivalent of a two-way ANOVA that can include interactions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78366/7290)).  There are mixed-effects versions of OLR (see my answer here: [Is there a two-way Friedman's test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/161872/7290)).  There are also mixed-effects versions of proportional hazards models that could be used (cf., R's [coxme](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxme/index.html)).  These assume the random effects are normally distributed.

With enough data (which you presumably have), you can count on the central limit theorem kicking in and use the [GEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation) (to understand the contrast between mixed models and the GEE, see my answer here: [Difference between generalized linear models & generalized linear mixed models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32421/7290)).

Another possibility is to aggregate the data into means that can be taken as independent and use standard methods to analyze the aggregates.  This will typically induce a loss of power, but can be a perfectly viable choice.

You state your data are non-normal, but you don't say much about the nature or extent of the non-normality.  It *may* be fine to use a linear mixed model.  Alternatively, if the issue is that you can't have negative distances, but otherwise the data are somewhat normal-ish, they may be approximately [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), and there are models for that as well.

Comment: I applied shapiro test. Both p.value and W are below limits. The reason for W being below limit is that multiple peaks appearing in the distribution. I will add the distributions asap.